# How to delay/postpone Gearman job?

Tags: gearman, task-management, python-gearman

I'm using **gearman** for synchronizing data on different servers. We have **1 main server** and, for example, 10 local servers. Let me describe one of possible situations. Say, gearman started working, and 5 jobs are done, data on that 5 servers is synced. When doing the next job is started, say, we lost the connection with server and it's not available right now. By the logic of gearman it retries again and again. So the remaining jobs (for servers 7, 8, 9, 10) will not be executed until the 6th is not done. The best solution would be postponing the job and putting it to the end of queue and continuing work of jobs 7-10.

If someone do know how to do that, please post the way.

PS: I'm using python.

Answer (score 0):

Gearman jobs can run in parallel or series.  Instead of using single jobs, you should use concurrent jobs (one for each server).

Answer (score 0):

```
GearmanClient.submit_multiple_jobs(jobs_to_submit, background=False, wait_until_complete=True, max_retries=0, poll_timeout=None)
```

This function will help. Just let background = True.

[This link](http://packages.python.org/gearman/client.html) will help, too.

Comment: in this case the process will be blocked, isn't it?

Comment: yes, I just give you the example of the method submit_multiple_jobs. If you set background=True, you can move on to the next line of your code.